# Vue.$router.push with same route but different parameters - how to trigger transition?

Tags: vuejs2

My application uses `this.$router.push` to change state. The first route is `/page/1`, the next `/page/2` and so on. My problem is, that since Vue doesn't reload the component, the transition effect is not triggered. How can I fix this? I don't mind if the whole component needs to be recreated.

Since there is no parent component I didn't find a way to use :key.

App.vue:

```
<collapse-transition origin="center" mode="out-in" :duration="250">
  <router-view/>
</collapse-transition>
```

router.ts:

```
{
  path: '/page/:case',
  name: 'Page',
  component: Page,
},
```

Page component:

```
this.$router.push("/page/" + case + 1)
```

Comment: Would it be an option if you you encapsulate the component itself in the `<collapse-transition />` markup instead of the router-view?

Comment: Have you try to give a different key to the component? [Check this documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements)
When toggling between elements that have the same tag name, you must tell Vue that they are distinct elements by giving them unique key attributes. Otherwise, Vue’s compiler will only replace the content of the element for efficiency. Even when technically unnecessary though, it’s considered good practice to always key multiple items within a <transition> component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I made it:

```
    <collapse-transition origin="center" mode="out-in" :duration="250">
        <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"/>
    </collapse-transition>
```